# Hibernate Database

Tags: java, hibernate

plz help me to solve the problem that i want to enter the unique name in sql using hibernae but if my new enterd name is match then it is replaced with the maching name how to solve it

Database Mapping class:

```
package org.asad.login.login.database; 
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
//@Table(name = "User")
public class DatabaseClass {


@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Test Class:

```
package org.asad.login.login.database;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    DatabaseClass db = new DatabaseClass();





ArrayList<DatabaseClass> user = new ArrayList<DatabaseClass>();

    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    user = (ArrayList<DatabaseClass>) s.createCriteria(DatabaseClass.class).list();
    s.beginTransaction();
    String name = new String();

    boolean check=false;
    do{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name");
        name = in.nextLine();
        for(int i=13; i<=user.size(); i++){
            db=(DatabaseClass) s.get(DatabaseClass.class, i);
            if(name.equals(db.getName())){
                System.out.println("Name already store");
                check = true;
            }
            else{
                check=false;
            }
        }
    }while(check==true);


    db.setName(name);
    s.save(db);

    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();



}}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logindb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">umar</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="org.asad.login.login.database.DatabaseClass"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your problem?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @GHajba  the problem is this that i first check that wheather the name is alredy exist or not if not then insert the username otherwise not but if username exist then i change the username but the new username is replace to the old username thats the problem.

Comment: Create new instance of `DatabaseClass` before setting new name.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your problem is that you load an entity from the database and change *its* name. This results in overwriting the `name` field of the same entity and not creating a new one.

To solve your problem create a new `DatabaseClass` object and set the new name there. Alternatively you can copy other information from the already found entity -- but at the end you have to save the *new* entity to the database.

And by the way you can find more easily if the name is matching one in the database: you could create a query like this one:

```
session.createCriteria(DatabaseClass.class).add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).uniqueResult();
```

to save you iteration over a list and comparing the elements by their name. Over time your solution with a bunch of users consumes a lot of memory and is not really maintainable if you do not update the list every time you change something.